# Insert code into <head> using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html-head

I have some code that looks something like this:

```
<head runat="server">
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var params = {};
     params.param1 = 'value1';
     params.param2 = 'value2';
     params.param3 = 'value3';
     params.param4 = ''; // ASP.NET value 1
     params.param5 = ''; // ASP.NET value 2
     function.call(params);
  </script>
</head>
```

How do I use ASP.NET to populate `param4` and `param5`? I've read about master pages and content placeholders, but is there a way that I can just do something like `params.param4 = '<%= var1 %>';` or `params.param4 = '<asp:var />';`?

### Edit

Thanks to everyone who answered so quickly. I must have had a parsing error or something that made me think this wasn't possible. Just to make it clear what I did to solve my problem:

**ASPX page:**

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var params = {};
     params.param1 = 'value1';
     params.param2 = 'value2';
     params.param3 = 'value3';
     params.param4 = '<%= var1 %>';
     params.param5 = '<%= var2 %>';
     function.call(params);
  </script>
</head>
```

**CS Code-Behind:**

```
public string var1 { get; set; }

public string var2 { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // setup code goes here
   var1 = 'param4';
   var2 = 'param5';
}
```

**Note:** You don't need `runat="server"` in the head, and just as long as the variables are public in the code-behind, they can be accessed via `<%= %>` in the `<head>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sort of answered your own question.  You can declare your variables in the code-behind and then use them in your code with `<%= %>` tags, or you can use the [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx) method to add the JavaScript to your page on the fly.

Comment: Heh, thanks. For some reason, I tried this yesterday but got errors when trying to use those tags. Not sure what I did differently this time, but whatever; it works now. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

you could do exactly that if  weren't **runat="server"**

alternatively you could render out that **params** array server-side

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("params", "'value1','value2','value3','" + value4 + "','" + value5 + "'");
```

Answer (score 1):

If your your values are public variables declared in the .cs part of the class you can do exactly what you described and read them out in server tags.